# When upvoting flashed "+2"

Tags: support, voting, upvotes

I was upvoting an answer and below the upvote button it briefly appeared a "+2".

I am unable to reproduce the situation again.

So what does the "+2" mean?

Comment: Link to the answer?

Comment: It was one of the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057010/is-there-a-tab-equivalent-of-stdendl-within-the-standard-library/22057209 , I don't remember which.

Comment: Thanks, the strange thing is I have achieved the 1000 reputation long long time ago and I never noticed the detailed view count before.

Comment: BTW, why the down votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I observe that you have >=1K rep, you likely accidentally clicked on the post score (which brings up the vote counts) and saw the `+2` below it (meaning 2 upvotes).

2 of the answers have 2 upvotes, so I can verify that it could have been the case.

Answer (score 6):

Just to expand on this, you have the [Established User privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

You saw something like this

[image]